# Refresh checkboxes javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a problem with checkboxes:
I have 2 menu that open 2 type of checkbox and I would like to have one all checked and the other not-checked when I refresh the page. this is the code:

```
<div id="Scena" class="tabcontent" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_frontale',true);"> Parete_frontale </input>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;margin-left:50px;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_destra', true);"> Parete_destra </input>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;margin-left:50px;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_sinistra', true);"> Parete_sinistra </input>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;margin-left:50px;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_p1', true);presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_p2', true);presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_p3', true);"> Parete_porta </input><br/> 
</div>

<div id="Indagini" class="tabcontent">
    <input type="checkbox" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="presenter.changeTexture('Parete_p2','back01_cervo.png');setInfoSofia(4);"> Image enhancement </input>
    <input type="checkbox" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="presenter.changeTexture('Parete_destra', 'destra_fluo.png');setInfoSofia(5);"> Analisi di Fluorescenza (LIF) </input>
    <input type="checkbox" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="setInfoSofia(6)"> Efflorescenze saline </input>
    <input type="checkbox" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="presenter.toggleSpotVisibility(HOP_ALL, true); presenter.enableOnHover(!presenter.isOnHoverEnabled()); hotspotSwitch();"> Indagini di caratterizzazione dei materiali </input>
</div>
```

I want all children of the div with id `Scena` to be checked and those of the div with id `Indagini` to be unchecked.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is an empty tag, it can't have content nor closing tag. Use `checked` attribute to mark an input checked. Note also, what is said about FireFox concerning page refreshing and `checked` attribute in the documentation.

Comment: <div id="Scena" class="tabcontent" >
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_frontale',true);"> Parete_frontale </input>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="cursor:hand;margin-left:50px;" onclick="presenter.toggleInstanceVisibilityByName('Parete_destra', true);"> Parete_destra </input></div>

Comment: this is part of the code with the attribute "checked" but i want it also at the page refresh

Comment: Please don't dump code snippets to comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: @Sofia_C, i see [javascript] tag at the bottom of your question. i guess you could write js function which will refresh your checkboxes on page load

Answer (score 1):

You can use "checked" option.So, by default all the Scena checkboxes will be checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" checkedstyle="cursor:hand;" onclick="" checked> Image enhancement
```

Comment: for the id "Scena" i have done it, my problem is for the page refresh. I want one menu all checked and the other non checked.

Comment: You can use jquery checked option, ('.ScenaClass').prop('checked', true); and ('.IndaginiClass').prop('checked', false); This can be done by giving the class to all the checkbox inside the Scene one.

Comment: Still, there is no such thing as a `</input>`.

Comment: Yes, OP need to remove </input> :)

Comment: Welcome,Let me know if there is any issues. $('.ScenaClass').prop('checked', true); forgot to add $ in the previous comment.